# Mac CD-ROM Media Location

Tags: mac, dvd, compact-disc

What is the equivalent of /etc/media of Linux in a Mac? In other words, what is the filesystem path of a mounted CD/DVD in a Mac?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

/Volumes/[Name of Media]

Comment: Cannot find it there.

Comment: Are you sure you are at the Root directory, and the media is mounted? This convention has been around for the longest time ever. in short, open Terminal, type : "cd /Volumes/", then "ls", and you should find the name of the media there

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using Finder.

With an active finder window press Command (Cmd) + Shift + G, on the small text field type "/Volumes" and finder should take you to that folder.